# ComboBox Styling

Tags: wpf, styles

I am very new to WPF and beg your pardon if this is so foolish. Don't ignore this a duplicated.

When I search through the internet to get to know how to style a `ComboBox`, I can find so many coding which is so lengthy. They have re-written style for all the parts in a `ComboBox`.

My Question is if I need to change only the toggle button's template of combobox how can I do that. I don't want write all the entire style for the combobox. Is this is possible to achieve?

Thank You in Advance.

**EDIT**

I will explain my issue further. I need to remove the light blue color appears when MouseOver the ComboBox. I think I can solve this by over wiring the Toggle button template of the Combobox. That is why I am searching is it possible to overwride a part (Only the toggle button) of the combobox.

Comment: is this what you want? http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/samples/example.htm

Comment: @TahirYasin - I think this not what i searching. :(

Comment: Got it, you are doing windows programming, but that solution is related to JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't an easy way to style just part of a control in WPF. You usually have to duplicate the original template and modify it for your own purposes.

The up side is that the templates for the controls (including the combobox) are widely available.

Here is a specific example of [modifying the toggle button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In that example, if you remove the triggers you should be able to get the result you want.

Comment: Is it possible to inherit exciting style and override selected part?

Comment: Not for existing templates. You CAN have your `style` **[basedon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx)** a existing style BUT the second you want to change the template (like you do) it will overwrite the existing one... Sorry.